# Load a controller into an other controller in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, controller

im developing a web application, using multiple pages, each with their own controller.

The problem now is that there are some variables in a controller, created for one page, that are required for an other page ( with a different controller).

Therefor i need to load one controller into the other one.

I did this by adding 
 App::import('Controller', 'sections');

$sections= new sectionsController;
$sections->constructClasses();

to the controller, but this doens't seem to work..

Maybe u guys have some ideas?

Thnx in advance!

Answer (score 4):

I think there're some misunderstandings in your mind about [MVC architectural pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).If you need some bullet for your gun,just get the bullet itself,and it's not neccessary to get another gun with it.So I hope you understand loading controller is really a bad idea.

Also if you want some variables accessable by all controllers,as Gaurav Sharma
mentioned ,you can use  `Configure::write()` to store data in the application’s configuration `app/config/core.php`.e.g

```
Configure::write('somekey',$someval);
```

Then you can get `$someval` by `Configure::read('somekey')` in any controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any one of the methods below to access a variable anywhere in the cakePHP application.
1.) use the **[configuration class](http://book.cakephp.org/view/43/Configure-Methods)** OR 
2.) use session for those variables

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on this this morning. I actually get the controller name from a database, but I've changed it to use variables instead.

```
$controller_name = "Posts"; // the name of the controller.
$action = "index"; // The action we want to call.

App::import('Controller', $controller_name); 

// Now we need the actual class name of the controller.
$controller_classname = $controller_name . 'Controller'; 

$Controller = new $controller_name;
$Controller->variable_name = "something"; // we can set class variables here too.

// Now invoke the dispatcher so that it will load and initialize everything (like components)
$d = new Dispatcher();
$d->_invoke($Controller, array('pass'=> '', 'action' => $action));

// And exit so it doesn't keep going.
exit(0);
```

I honestly didn't bother figuring out what 'pass' is for (I assume variables), but it throws a warning without it.
You will also need to explicitly call `$this->render` in your `$action`.

Comment: `pass` is half of the `passedArgs` variable in the Controller. If you use Dispatcher::dispatch() rather than _invoke, it will set these for you, in addition to doing other potentially useful things (but also potentially unnecessary for your purposes).